# Strange dropdown menu jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I developed this website: http://loloey.com/forme/formeeng.html
I have a very strange problem with the dropdown menu in the top left of the page called "Change Universe": when I hover many times on this dropdown menu, the dropdown elements disappears!!!
The problem persist on all the browsers like firefox, explorer 9, chrome etc etc.

I created this menu with a simple jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
$('#nav li').hover(
    function () {
        //show its submenu
        $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(100);
    }, 
    function () {
        //hide its submenu
        $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(100);                      
    }
);

});
```

This is the css:

```
/*---- CROSS BROWSER DROPDOWN MENU ----*/

#nav {

padding-left: 90px;
margin-top:-15px;
list-style: none;
float: left;
font-family: 'helveticaneuelight', Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 9px;
color: #fff;
}   

    /* make the LI display inline */
    /* it's position relative so that position absolute */
    /* can be used in submenu */
    #nav li {
        float:left; 
        display:block; 
        width:70px; 
        background:#808184; 
        position:relative;
        z-index:500; 
        margin:0 1px;
    }

    /* this is the parent menu */
    #nav li a {
display: block;
padding: 5px 5px 4px 1px;
height: 11px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #58595B;
text-align: left;
    }

    #nav li a:hover {
        color:#fff;
    }

    /* you can make a different style for default selected value */
    #nav a.selected {
        color:#f00;
    }

    /* submenu, it's hidden by default */
    #nav ul {
        position:absolute; 
        left:0; 
        display:none; 
        margin:0 0 0 -1px; 
        padding:0; 
        list-style:none;
    }

    #nav ul li {
        width:70px; 
        float:left; 
    }

    /* display block will make the link fill the whole area of LI */
    #nav ul a {
display: block;
height: 15px;
padding: 4px 5px;
color: #58595B;
    }

    #nav ul a:hover {
        text-decoration:none;   
    }

    /* fix ie6 small issue */
    /* we should always avoid using hack like this */
    /* should put it into separate file : ) */
    *html #nav ul {
        margin:0 0 0 -2px;
    }
```

And this is the html:

```
<div id="cambia">
  <div class="top_a">CHANGE UNIVERSE:</div>
  <ul id="nav">


<li><a href="#">FORME</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="../grandfloor/grandflooreng.html">GRANDFLOOR</a></li>
    <li><a href="../gdo/gdoeng.html">GDO</a></li>
    <li><a href="../parsi/parsieng.html">PARSI</a></li>
  </ul>         
    <div class="clear"></div>
</li>   
  </ul>
</div>
```

Anyone that help me?

Comment: The height of the UL reduces to 0%. You may want to modify your selector to only affect the main LI, i.e. `#nav > li`

Comment: It's not finishing animation on one of the functions(slideDown or slideUp) if you hover over and out quickly. I had this issue before. The answer is - stop playing :)

Answer (score 0):

try with `stop(true,true)`

> If the clearQueue parameter is provided with a value of true, then the rest of the animations in the queue are removed and never run.

```
$(this).stop(true,true).slideDown(100);
```

Comment: I try with $('ul', this).stop(true,true).slideDown(100); but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can try be below hack

Here is the working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/QM73r/

...

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

    $('#nav li').hover(
        function () {
            //show its submenu
            $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(100);

        }, 
        function () {
            //hide its submenu
            $('ul').attr('style', 'display:block');
            $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(100);

        }
    );
```